# How to select objects with jq which have a string array field that is a superset of an input array

Tags: jq

An example is to return objects that have both "value-1" and "value-2" in the "field" property, using jq.

Objects:

```
[
  {
    "field": ["value-1", "value-2", "value-3"]
  },
  {
    "field": ["value-1", "value-2", "value-34"]
  },
  {
    "field": ["value-3", "value-1", "value-4", "value-5"]
  }
]
```

Return:

```
{
  "field": ["value-1", "value-2", "value-3"]
},
{
  "field": ["value-3", "value-1", "value-4", "value-5"]
}
```

I've found many examples for selecting objects that include at least one value from an array (e.g. return objects where the "field" property includes "value-1" or "value-2"), but I didn't find any examples to match all values. At first glance, some of the functions in jq, such as `contains` looked like they might be useful here, but actually match on substrings instead and I need exact match only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the updated question, going by `all` and `IN` is the best approach. Here is a reformatted version of it:

```bash
.[] | select(. as {$field} | all("value-1", "value-3"; IN($field[])))
```

However, with arrays of rather manageable lengths, you could also go by a less efficient array subtraction. If all items were present, the resulting array is expected to be empty:

```bash
.[] | select(["value-1", "value-3"] - .field == [])
```

```json
{
  "field": [
    "value-1",
    "value-2",
    "value-3"
  ]
}
{
  "field": [
    "value-3",
    "value-1",
    "value-4",
    "value-5"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Svv8Y6T0Lgf)

Comment: Nice. Yes that works for the arrays of numbers that were in my original question. My actually data set is arrays of strings and in that case contains matches substrings. I've updated the example in the question to be strings. My mistake oversimplifying the example

Comment: @FiveOFive Well, in that case, just use `tonumber` to convert the strings to numbers: `.[] | select(.field | map(tonumber) | contains([1,3]))`. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/az4vsv9EAtH)

Comment: I've updated the example to be more clear that the strings are not numeric

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this using the `IN` sql like operator.

`.[] | select(.field as $field | ["value-1", "value-3"] | all(IN($field[])))`

Here's a jq play demo - https://jqplay.org/s/spEokLaWUHL

Looking forward to hearing if there are any other ways to do this filtering